# MFC: Bitmap based graphics and sizing to screen and printer with precision?

Tags: printing, graphics, bitmap, mfc

Since a bitmap based graphic deals with pixels and not measurements.  How do you relate size on screen to printed size so there is precision between the two.   Presuming using MFC and the `OnDraw()` method of screen and printer output for the graphic.  Would I need to use the `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` on the screen DC and save it to a variable, then when printing, get same values and calculate correct values for `SetViewPortExt` based on the ratio?

TIA!!

Comment: You are using the term *"precision"* in a way that doesn't make sense. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: In that you have a bitmap, what is its true size and if having it on screen, to print to be same size.

Comment: @IInspectable I think he means he has a image that is 250 pixels wide and now needs to proportionately represent that in the correct units for the printer.

I think you have an agreed area that represents a page (in pixels) and you have the printable page area (in mm) and apply a scale factor to go from one to another.

Comment: A bitmap doesn't have a *"true size"*. It's an array of values. Some image formats (including BMP) can store metadata information (like the resolution in terms of physical units). The resolution is generally ignored when an image is displayed on a raster device, like a computer screen. It's unclear what you want to accomplish with printing. There is no unique mapping to *"resolution gets ignored"* for a different output device.

Comment: exactly what i'm talking about. bitmap graphics represented in pixels.  So how to you keep the size between screen and printer.